# Fire click event for nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying with a modal window popup. Essentially it come in and takes over the whole window.

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="closeBox"><span id="x">X</span></div>
        <form>
            form stuff..
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I target my `#closeBox` like..

```
$("#closeBox").click(function() {
    $("#popup").remove();   
});
```

The event never fires. I believe this is because it is nested, if I switched `#closeBox` to `html` the event fires and it works, as it does if I switch it to `#popup`. How can I target the nested element so that it only fires when `#closeBox` is clicked?

Comment: Is the popup added dynamically, or in your markup all along but hidden and then made visible?

Comment: I use `.load()` to bring it in after a `setTimeout`

Comment: For me it's working as excepted.. See my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/12kuz9ev/)

Comment: If you're using `$("#popup").load(...)` then the `#popup` element exists all along and so can have click handlers assigned to it. But the `#closeBox"` element won't exist until *after* the `.load()` and so can't have a click handler assigned until after the load is complete. Or use a delegated handler: `$("#popup").on("click", "#closeBox", function() { ... });`

Comment: if the popup is dynamically created, use delegates for binding the events. Otherwise bind the events in document.ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "delegate" to attach a handler to the DOM element

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "#closeBox", "click", function() {
  $("#popup").remove();  
});
```